Combining both regression training and classification Evaluation for a single task
I was given a task which involved video summarization using AI. My initial thought was to use a basic classification model based on image features. However, after reading papers and conducting some research, I found that this approach would likely only identify frames that seem important, rather than providing an actual summary. If I want a true summary, I need to treat the video more like segments and predict the important segments within the video.
In almost all previous work on this task, researchers have taken the labels (frame scores) and converted them into a key shot summary, which is a Boolean array. This is done by taking the average scores of each video segment. The video segments themselves are derived from the features of the frames using Kernel Temporal Segmentation (KTS).
Thus, we now have two forms of labels: the continuous values (scores) and the Boolean summary. I found that some researchers train a regression model on the continuous values and evaluate this model using Mean Squared Error (MSE). After each evaluation, the model's predictions are converted to the key shot summary form (Boolean summary), which is then compared to the key shot summary labels. Subsequently, the F-score is used to evaluate each epoch. Others use a classification model and change the loss function to Binary Cross-Entropy (BCE) but also train on the continuous values.
My question is, if I achieve better results using the regression network, should I only use regression evaluation metrics (MAE, MSE, RMSE) and consider the conversion to Boolean summary as just postprocessing? Or is it acceptable to use MSE in the regression to try and mimic the ground truth scores, convert them, then compare them with the ground truth summary and calculate the F-score?
